# How do I set view visiibility in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I started using ConstraintLayout a few weeks ago and I am finding (I believe) that it has many bugs. One huge issue is that I cannot set view visibilities. The following code does not work:

```
<TextView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/sampleView"
    style="@style/RSTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:text="sample text"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:shadowColor="#00000000"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/privacyPolicyText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enterAgreementText1" />
```

You can see I've marked it as "gone", but when I run and inspect the view using the layout inspector, visibility is STILL set to visible. I've had to come up with hacky solutions to this involving setting the alpha to 0 and isEnabled to false when I want a view to be gone and vice versa. When I try to set the visibility programmatically, I have the same issue:

```
sampleView.visibility = ConstraintLayout.GONE
```

This still results in a visible view. This is driving me nuts because I'm forced to make multi-line hacky solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any kind of Group in this ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Yes I'm also trying to use groups. Which I've also had issues with. Setting a groups visibility to GONE doesn't change anything either

Comment: Group visibility overrides normal view's visibility.

Comment: Okay, after playing around with groups, it seems that when I put a view with visibility set to gone in a group , and the group's visibility is unset, the view's visibility is set to VISIBLE. This has to be the issue. I thought that if the groups visibility was unset, it wouldn't override anything

Comment: are there any other issues

Comment: No this is the solution, I just posted an answer mentioning you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful using Groups in Constraint Layout. Main things to note while using groups are

- **Group's visibility overrides normal view's visibility**
- **If the group's visibility is unset, it defaults to visible and overrides your view's visibility.**

While using Constraint Layout be careful in using Groups. I think almost all visibility issues in constraint layout are caused by groups.

Comment: This solved my issue, but as I'm refactoring, I'm finding that if a group's alpha is set, it doesn't override the alpha of the views in the group. Why would it override visibility and not alpha?

Comment: A Group can only be used to control visibility of the Views. Anything else you set to a Group will not effect Views

Comment: @sadelbrid Try avoiding the use of Groups in complex use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the below links I found are related to your problem:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37151322
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37139335
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37138937
 
but they are all filed reports about problems/bugs concerning the visibility of views inside a ConstraintLayout.  
Check them.

Answer (score 0):

@Pavan Varma pointed out that Group visibility overrides the view's visibility. I thought that if the groups visibility was unset, it wouldn't override anything, but it still does. If you're having issues with visibility in ContraintLayouts, pay close attention to its group's visibility that overrides it. If the group's visibility is unset, it defaults to visible and overrides your view's visibility.